# Why does the GIF colour palette get corrupted in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, gif

I made a function that captions a GIF or image:

```py
import textwrap
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps, ImageSequence


def caption(fn: str, text: str):
    old_im = Image.open(fn)
    ft = old_im.format
    W = old_im.size[0]
    font = ImageFont.truetype('BebasNeue.ttf', 50) # replace with your own font

    width = 10
    while True:
        lines = textwrap.wrap(text, width=width)
        if (font.getsize(max(lines, key=len))[0]) > (0.9 * W):
            break
        width += 1

    # amount of lines * height of one line
    bar_height = len(lines) * (font.getsize(lines[0])[1])
    frames = []
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(old_im):
        frame = ImageOps.expand(
            frame,
            border=(0, bar_height, 0, 0),
            fill='white'
        )
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame)
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            w, h = draw.multiline_textsize(line, font=font)
            # Position is x: centered, y: line number * height of line
            draw.text(
                ((W - w) / 2, i * h),
                line,
                font=font,
                fill='black'
            )

        del draw
        b = BytesIO()
        frame.save(b, format=ft)
        b.seek(0)
        frames.append(Image.open(b))

    frames[0].save(
        f'out.{ft}',
        save_all=True,
        append_images=frames[1:],
        format=ft,
        loop=0,
        optimize=True
    )


caption(
    'in.gif',
    'this is a test message this is a test message this is a test message this is a test message this is a test message this is a test message'
)
```

This, with slight variations, is giving weird results, of which none are desired.

This is `in.gif`:

[image]

1. With no changes to the code above:

[image]

2. With `palette=old_im.palette` passed into `frames[0].save()`:

[image]

3. With the frame converted to 'RGB' (`.convert('RGB'))`) immediately after expanding it:

[image]

4. With `palette=old_im.palette` passed into `frames[0].save(...)` **and** the frame converted to 'RGB' (`.convert('RGB'))`) immediately after expanding it:

[image]

5. With `palette=old_im.getpalette()` passed into `frames[0].save(...)`:

[image]

6. With `palette=old_im.getpalette()` passed into `frames[0].save(...)` **and** the frame converted to 'RGB' (`.convert('RGB'))`) immediately after expanding it:

[image]

As you can see none of the options have the desired output, though number 5 seems to have the best results, apart from the black text on white canvas now suddenly being dark red text on a red canvas. What is causing this and how could I get a normal output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `'RGB'` BEFORE expanding the `frame`:

```py
# [...]
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(old_im):
    frame = frame.convert('RGB')                # <--
    frame = ImageOps.expand(
        frame,
        border=(0, bar_height, 0, 0),
        fill='white'
    )
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame)
# [...]
```

That's the output I then get:

[image: Output]

I assume, that filling with `white` somehow corrupts the existing palette. If you convert to `'RGB'` before expanding, "white" will be the "correct white", I guess.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Pillow:        8.1.2
----------------------------------------
```